# Unity the The type IRegisterAutoMapper does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi I am using Unity as my IoC container and am trying to get an instance of an object using ServiceLocator.

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IAutoMapperRegisterFactory>()
```

I have set in my configuration file the object that unity has to instantiate:

```
container.RegisterType<IAutoMapperRegisterFactory, AutoMapperRegisterFactory>();
```

Now my curent AutoMapperRegisterFactory looks something like this:

```
public class AutoMapperRegisterFactory : IAutoMapperRegisterFactory
{
    private readonly IRegisterAutoMapper m_RegisterAutoMapper;

    public AutoMapperRegisterFactory(IRegisterAutoMapper registerAutoMapper)
    {
        m_RegisterAutoMapper = registerAutoMapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IRegisterAutoMapper> GetRegisteredAutoMappers()
    {
        var registeredAutoMappers = new List<IRegisterAutoMapper> { m_RegisterAutoMapper };
        return registeredAutoMappers;
    }
}
```

And if I try to run this I get this error:

```
 The type IRegisterAutoMapper does not have an accessible constructor.
```

Previously my AutomapperRegisterFactory looked like this:

```
public class AutoMapperRegisterFactory : IAutoMapperRegisterFactory
{
    public IEnumerable<IRegisterAutoMapper> GetRegisteredAutoMappers()
    {
        var registeredAutoMappers = new List<IRegisterAutoMapper> { new RegisterAutoMapper(new RegisterMappings(), new RegisterCustomMappings()) };
        return registeredAutoMappers;
    }
}
```

And everything worked just fine.What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Component `AutoMapperRegisterFactory` requre as dependency `IRegisterAutoMapper` component.
`IRegisterAutoMapper` implemented by `RegisterAutoMapper` type, but constructor of `RegisterAutoMapper` type require two arguments: `RegisterMappings` and `RegisterCustomMappings`, so you must provide them.

**For example:**

```
container.RegisterType<..., RegisterMappings>();
container.RegisterType<..., RegisterCustomMappings>();
```